# Get Multiple Selected checkboxes in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a ProductController which is consists of Create method.

My Model :

```
public class ProductEntry
{
    public Crescent.LinqModel.Product Products { get; set; }
    public ProductSKU SKUs { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> pColors { get; set; }

    public ProductEntry()
    {
        pColors = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
}
```

Create Get Method :

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        CrescentAdmin.Models.ProductEntry product = new CrescentAdmin.Models.ProductEntry();
        var colors = _appData.GetProductColors().ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
                product.pColors.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = colors[i].Name.ToString(), Text = colors[i].Name, Selected = true });
            else
                product.pColors.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = colors[i].Name.ToString(), Text = colors[i].Name });
        }

        return View(product);
    }
```

this colors i want to fill in the list of checkboxes in which i can select multiple checkboxes.its working properly.

Create Post :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Create(CrescentAdmin.Models.ProductEntry entry, HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
    {
      //code to insert in two table
      // required to fetch which checkboxes are selected ??    
    }
```

Create View :

```
       @model CrescentAdmin.Models.ProductEntry
```

code to fill list of checkboxes :

```
         <tr>
            <td>
                Product Colors
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (Model.pColors != null && Model.pColors.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Model.pColors.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //if (Model.pColors[i])
                        //{
                            <input type="checkbox" value="@Model.pColors[i].Value" id="@Model.pColors[i].Value"/> @Model.pColors[i].Text <br />
                             @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.pColors[i].Value);
                             @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.pColors[i].Text);
                             @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.pColors[i].Selected);
                        //}
                        //else
                        //{
                        //    <input type="checkbox" value="@Model.pColors[i].Value" /> @Model.productColors[i].Name <br />
                        //}
                    }
                }


                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SKUs.ProductColors)
            </td>
        </tr>
```

i have tried this code , but no luck !!

required to fetch which checkboxes are selected ??   Please help

Comment: Please show your view

Comment: Did you try `@Html.CheckBoxFor`

Comment: @Rogier21 - how will i write in this context ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.pColors[i].Value);
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.pColors[i].Text);
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.pColors[i].Selected);
```

Comment: it worked for me , now able to take number of selected checkboxes :) but one more question will help please ?

Comment: i have model properties which are of bit datatype. i want to put checkbox for that and get on post method. i have done this code :<tr>
                <td>
                    Jewish
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBox("Jewish", new { id = "chkJewish" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SKUs.Jewish)
                </td>
            </tr> but on post not getting weather its selected or not..

Comment: try same here `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model.SKUs.Jewish, new { id = "chkJewish" })`

Comment: i tried this : @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SKUs.Jewish, new { id = "chkJewish" }) gives error that cant convert bool? to bool

Comment: Then try this: `@Html.CheckBox("SKUs.Jewish", (bool)Model.SKUs.Jewish, new { id = "chkJewish" })`

Comment: Is Jewish nullable bit? Which object is null and causes error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31564/discussion-between-dharappatel-and-karaxuna)

Comment: your last answer :@Html.CheckBox("SKUs.Jewish", (bool?)Model.SKUs.Jewish ?? false, new { id = "chkJewish" }) also not working..

Answer (score 24):

I normally use below approach when dealing with checkboxes check whether it helps you.

**Model:**

```
namespace GateApplication.Models
{
    public class Gate
    {
        public string PreprationRequired { get; set; }
        public List<CheckBoxes>  lstPreprationRequired{ get; set; }
        public string[] CategoryIds { get; set; }
    }

    public class CheckBoxes
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool Checked { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

Load CheckBox Value:

```
public ActionResult Create()
   {
      List<CheckBoxes> lstchk = new List<CheckBoxes>()
            {
                new CheckBoxes {Text="coduit", Value="coduit" },
                new CheckBoxes {Text="safety", Value="safety" },
                new CheckBoxes {Text="power", Value="power" },
                new CheckBoxes {Text="access", Value="access" }
            };

          var model = new Gate
            {
               lstPreprationRequired=lstchk
            };

            return View(model);
   }
```

**View:**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.lstPreprationRequired)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" id="@item.Value" name="CategoryIds" value="@item.Text"/>
                  <label for="optionId">@item.Text</label>
       <br />
    }
```

Now your view shold have list of checkboxes. Now saving CheckBox values to the database.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {

            Gate gate = new Gate();
            TryUpdateModel(gate);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                gate.PreprationRequired = Request.Form["CategoryIds"];// here you'll get a string containing a list of checked values of the checkbox list separated by commas

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(gate.PreprationRequired))//this is used when no checkbox is checked
                    gate.PreprationRequired = "None,None";

                Save();//Save to database
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Now you have below kind of string in your database

> safety,power,access

Now fetch the selected values and display the view.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
           List<CheckBoxes> lstchk = new List<CheckBoxes>()
            {
                new CheckBoxes {Text="coduit", Value="coduit" },
                new CheckBoxes {Text="safety", Value="safety" },
                new CheckBoxes {Text="power", Value="power" },
                new CheckBoxes {Text="access", Value="access" }
             };

            var model = new Gate
            {
                lstPreprationRequired =lstchk,
                CategoryIds = "safety,power,access".Split(',')//here get your comma separated list from database and assign it to the CategoryIds string array, i have used sample text for the values
            };

            return View(model);
        }
```

**View:**

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.lstPreprationRequired)
        {
             <input type="checkbox" id="@item.Value" name="CategoryIds" value="@item.Text" 
             @foreach (var c in Model.CategoryIds)
             {
               if(c == item.Value)
               {
                  <text> checked="checked"</text>
               }
             }/>
             <label for="optionId">@item.Text></label>
        }
```

Let me know if this does not help you.

Comment: It was awesome :)

Comment: Thanks big . I just couldn't get the View-Model items setup right. I had the name of the checkboxes with the '[]' suffix on them. Once I removed those, and ensured the Model's property was a string array, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Me too was having a scenario like you and I implemented it using EditorFor by referring this link "[ASP.NET MVC - Multiple checkboxes for row selection in HTML table](http://www.iminfo.in/post/mvc-multiple-checkboxes-select-in-html-table-bootstrap)"

For that you need create a EditorTemplate folder and need to add the view with a same name of model. View code like below

```
@model EditorForSample.Models.ProductViewModel


<tr>
  <td class="text-nowrap">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Selected, new {@class="chkSelect"})  </td>
<td colspan="3">
    @Model.Name
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
</td>
<td>
    @Model.Price
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Price)
</td>
```

Model can be like below.

```
public class ProductPageViewModel
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public List<ProductViewModel> ProductsList { get; set; }
}

public class ProductViewModel
{
    public bool Selected{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

And in parent view you can write html like below

```
 .......
  <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="checkbox" id="chkSelectAll" /></th>
                    <th colspan="3">
                        Product Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Cost
                    </th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ProductsList)
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
.........
```

Above link has sample project too. I know answer of this question is already accepted but just sharing this. It may help someone. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

```js
<script>
   $("#btndownloading").click(function (e) {
                var ckebox_value = $("input[name=cmmdLabels]:checked").map(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() != 0) {
                        return $(this).val();
                    }
                }).get();
                var ckeck_box_length = ckebox_value.length;
                if (ckeck_box_length != 0) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("dowloadingfile", "dowloading")',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ selectionvalue_ck: ckebox_value }),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {

                        }, 
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    alert("Please select at least one File");
                }
            });
</script>

 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult dowloadingfile(string[] selectionvalue_ck)
        {
   string fileName = "";
   for (int j = 0; j < selectionvalue.Length; j++)
                {
     fileName = selectionvalue_ck[j];
    }
  }
```

```html
<input class="cb-element" name="cmmdLabels" value="1.txt" type="checkbox">
<input class="cb-element" name="cmmdLabels" value="2.txt" type="checkbox">
<input class="cb-element" name="cmmdLabels" value="3.txt" type="checkbox">
<input class="cb-element" name="cmmdLabels" value="4.txt" type="checkbox">
<input class="cb-element" name="cmmdLabels" value="5.txt" type="checkbox">

<button id="btndownloading">Download file</button>
```

Comment: Have in mind that answers which contain only code are not considered complete.

Answer (score 0):

I use this extension:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxListFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TProperty>>> expression,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> multiSelectList,
    Object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    // Derive property name for checkbox name
    var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (body == null)
        return null;

    String propertyName = body.Member.Name;

    // Get currently select values from the ViewData model
    IEnumerable<TProperty> list = expression.Compile().Invoke(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);

    // Convert selected value list to a List<String> for easy manipulation
    var selectedValues = new List<String>();

    if (list != null)
        selectedValues = new List<TProperty>(list).ConvertAll(i => i.ToString());

    // Create div
    var ulTag = new TagBuilder("ul");
    ulTag.AddCssClass("checkBoxList");
    ulTag.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes), true);

    // Add checkboxes
    foreach (var item in multiSelectList)
    {
        ulTag.InnerHtml += String.Format(
            "<li><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"{0}\" id=\"{0}_{1}\" value=\"{1}\" {2} /><label for=\"{0}_{1}\">{3}</label></li>",
            propertyName,
            item.Value,
            selectedValues.Contains(item.Value) ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "",
            item.Text);
    }

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(ulTag.ToString());
}
```